# Nested control structures, averaging script

Tags: java

Making a script using nested control structures that will average ANY numbers from 0 to 100, producing an error if any numbers are above 100 or below 0.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ExerciseSix
{
public static void main( String[] args )
{

    Scanner dylan = new Scanner(System.in);

    int gradeCounter;
    int total;
    int grade;
    double average;

    total = 0;
    gradeCounter = 0;

    System.out.println( "Enter a grade or -1 to quit: " );
    grade = dylan.nextInt();

    while ( grade != -1 )
    {

        total = total + grade;
        gradeCounter = gradeCounter + 1;





        System.out.println( "Enter grade or -1 to quit: ");
        grade = dylan.nextInt();


        if ( grade > 100 );
        System.out.println( "Number too large");            

        if ( grade < 0 );
        System.out.println( "Number too small");
    }


    if ( gradeCounter != 0 )

    {

        average = (double) total / gradeCounter;


        System.out.printf( "Class average is %.2f", average );



    }

    else
        System.out.println( "No grades were entered" );

}
```

I am not getting any compile errors, BUT when I type a number in, the first number goes in properly. THEN no matter what number I type in between 0 and 100, it says

"5
 Number too large
 Number too small
 Enter grade or -1 to quit: "

I think the large numbers are being added to the average also

Answer (score 2):

Remove the semicolons in your if statements

change

```
if ( grade > 100 );
    System.out.println( "Number too large");            

if ( grade < 0 );
    System.out.println( "Number too small");
```

to

```
if ( grade > 100 )
    System.out.println( "Number too large");            

if ( grade < 0 )
    System.out.println( "Number too small");
```

A best practice is to enclose all if statements with curly braces so you don't get any unexpected behavior

```
if ( grade > 100 ){
    System.out.println( "Number too large");  
}
```

As for the large numbers being added to the total, you will want to do data validation before the calculation, i.e.

```
while(grade != -1){
    if( grade > 100 || grade < 0) {
    //Message
    }
    else{
    //Total calculation
    }
}
```

Comment: Alright, I got that corrected. But how can I create the number thats too large or too small from being entered into whats going to be averaged? Should I put something after this line: System.out.println( "Number too large, enter a new number");   
   }

Comment: I have the script telling you that you cannot enter that number and to enter a new number, but the script still saves the number that was too large or too small and adds it in the average

Comment: @Darkcobra94 See my third point. Place your average calculation after the if statement checking if the numbers are too small or too large.

Comment: It seems that the calculation is behind the if statements that check if the numbers are too small or too large, but where should it go? if( grade > 100 || grade < 0) Its saying if the grade is greater than 100 or less than 0 then? Shouldn't I make it destroy the large or small number or something and then repeat the "Enter a number... " line?